# how do sites automagically grab profile pictures?

Tags: automation, profile, image, gravatar

Some sites have the ability to grab your profile picture after you sign up for the first time without the user actually uploading a pic. I think stackoverflow has this functionality at sign as well....How does it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

stackoverflow uses [gravatars](http://gravatar.com) which are linked by your email address. You can read more about [how gravatar works on their developer resources page.](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/)

Answer (score 6):

It uses gravatar.com I believe. You associate an avatar with your email and then sites can use your email to locate your avatar. There is a plugin for Wordpress. Or google search 'gravatar API' to put it on your own site.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

There is a site called http://gravatar.com that takes a MD5 hash of your email to load a profile picture

Answer (score 1):

They're using OpenID.  Some OpenID providers allow you to upload a profile picture or it wil associate it with your Gravatar's e-mail address (http://en.gravatar.com/).